# Unable to find the IOnlineStatus interface in a Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, wcf, p2p

I tried to do a small chat application in Silverlight.

```
var status = _channel.GetProperty<IOnlineStatus>();
```

In Silverlight 4 no IOnlineStatus exists.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't such an interface in Silverrlight.
what's the type of _channel ?

Comment: IChatChannel...

And 

    public interface IChatService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Join(string memberName);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Leave(string memberName);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string memberName, string message);
    }

    public interface IChatChannel : IChatService, IClientChannel
    {
    }

Comment: that has nothing to do with Silverlight itself. Is a part of a WCF web-service that you need to create and import into your Silverlight application.

Comment: Thats strange! May exists a reason to remove it ?